# Pattern matching expressions that have been simplified

Tags: pattern-matching, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I run into this type of issue frequently when trying to apply known identities to complicated expressions: some of my expressions will have their forms simplified by mathematica in such a way that mathematica will not be capable of easily pattern-matching uniformly all the expressions. What are good ways of preventing premature reductions of complex expressions so that I can pattern match everything nicely?

Here's a simple example.

Say we have a table involving numbers $a,b$ generated as follows:

```
arr = Table[i*j a^i b^j, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a b & 2 a b^2 & 3 a b^3 & 4 a b^4 & 5 a b^5 \\
 2 a^2 b & 4 a^2 b^2 & 6 a^2 b^3 & 8 a^2 b^4 & 10 a^2 b^5 \\
 3 a^3 b & 6 a^3 b^2 & 9 a^3 b^3 & 12 a^3 b^4 & 15 a^3 b^5 \\
 4 a^4 b & 8 a^4 b^2 & 12 a^4 b^3 & 16 a^4 b^4 & 20 a^4 b^5 \\
 5 a^5 b & 10 a^5 b^2 & 15 a^5 b^3 & 20 a^5 b^4 & 25 a^5 b^5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

and furthermore let's say that we're working in regime for which $a,b$ are each so small that if the total power on both of them is larger than $5$ the term can be neglected. Then we might try to implement this via

```
arr /. a^i_ b^j_ :> RuleCondition[0, i + j > 5]
```

but the output is actually

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a b & 2 a b^2 & 3 a b^3 & 4 a b^4 & 5 a b^5 \\
 2 a^2 b & 4 a^2 b^2 & 6 a^2 b^3 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 a^3 b & 6 a^3 b^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 a^4 b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 5 a^5 b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

because even though the terms in the corners are order $6$ they are not of the form given by the pattern since $5ab^5$ is represented as `Times[5,Power[a,5],b]`. Since there is no `Power` on the `b` it isn't matched by the pattern. Are there any ways to handle the corner cases without hardcoding new patterns especially for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Optional in your pattern, which has the short form of `.`:

```
arr = Table[i*j a^i b^j, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}];

arr /. a^i_. b^j_. :> RuleCondition[0, i + j > 5] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  a b & 2 a b^2 & 3 a b^3 & 4 a b^4 & 0 \\
>  2 a^2 b & 4 a^2 b^2 & 6 a^2 b^3 & 0 & 0 \\
>  3 a^3 b & 6 a^3 b^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  4 a^4 b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Another alternative is to use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series):

```
Series[arr /. s:(a|b) -> s t, {t, 0, 5}] //Normal //ReplaceAll[t->1] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  a b & 2 a b^2 & 3 a b^3 & 4 a b^4 & 0 \\
>  2 a^2 b & 4 a^2 b^2 & 6 a^2 b^3 & 0 & 0 \\
>  3 a^3 b & 6 a^3 b^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  4 a^4 b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Wow, using `.` seems obvious now but I would not have thought of it!

Comment: Why isn't `RuleCondition` documented? Its usage has been discussed on this site for years and there doesn't seem to be any reason not to have this documented

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch special treat for stackexchange users I guess...